# gluLookAt is optional?

Tags: opengl, option-type, glulookat

I am new to Open GL / Open GL ES.

I am a Android developer and exploring Open GL myself. Is really very difficult to understand but day by day I am making progress merely because of you peoples :)

Now lets come to my problem.

I downloaded 2 sample, compile and run it...it working. But when I looked in a code I found out of one **gluLookAt() is not being used**.

My question is,
 1) **is it optional** ?
 2) **And if its then how we setting the ViewPort(Camera)** ?

Please let me know if need more description on it.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gluLookAt()` has always been totally optional. It is just a convenience function which sets up a transformation matrix for a translation (for the camera position) and a rotation (for camera orientation). Also note that `gluLookAt()` is also totally deprecated and not availbale in modern OpenGL.